# How to retrieve data prior to running an activity

Tags: android

I have 2 fragments.

Fragment 1
Loads sharedpreference to display string

Fragment 2
Saves sharedprefence for string

Is it possible to retrieve that string in my first Fragment without running the second Fragment?

Comment: What string do you want to retrieve?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You just need to make sure you are reading with the same key you used to write with:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);

 // Reading from SharedPreferences
 String value = prefs.getString("myKey", "defaultValue");
 Log.d(LOG_TAG, value);
```

Note that we've assigned a defaultValue as the return value here. If there is no value with the key "myKey" in your shared prefs, it will instead return "defaultValue". This is a nice safeguard, think of it like a null pointer check - you will always get a value from `getString()`, even if it's just the default.

You don't need to be in the same activity for this to work, you just need to make sure that 1) your preferences name is the same and 2) the key used to store the value is the same in both spots.

Comment: This doesnt give me the string. It seems as though it is not saving to the sharedprefs because the second fragment that saves the string is not being ran yet because it always shows the defualt value UNTIL I open my second fragment that has the value I want.

Comment: @th3ramr0d Of course, you have to save a value before you can retrieve it. It sounds like you need to refactor your code so that you can do this.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't get confuse between `Activity` and `Fragment`.

And yes, you can.